# Pandas data frame : how to check all value of last row if it is non zero

Tags: python, dataframe

i want to check last row's all value if it is non-zero,if it is non zero then give me column name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,-2,0,0], 'B': [0, 0, 0, 3, -2], 'C' : [0, 0, -2, 4, 0], 'D': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df.columns[(df.iloc[[-1]] != 0).all()]
```

Output:

```
Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

---

If you wish to get only column name then use:

```
df.columns[(df.iloc[[-1]] != 0).all()][0]
```

Output:

```
'B'
```

---

Explanation:

This line returns a boolean mask of the last row if the value is non-zero.

```
(df.iloc[[-1]] != 0).all()
   A     B      C      D
4  False  True  False  False
```

This line applies the boolean mask to the column names of the data frame.

```
df.columns[]
```